# Android Activity Navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm very new to android development and I'm working on an application where I have 4 activities. Each activity needs to be able to navigate to any of the other 3. So I created 4 buttons at the top of each activity that allow for this. The XML code looks like this:

```
<Button ... android:onClick="loadProfileLayout"/>  
<Button ... android:onClick="loadRulesLayout"/>  
<Button ... android:onClick="loadSettingsLayout"/>  
<Button ... android:onClick="loadHelpLayout"/>
```

the manifest has an activity tag for each:

```
    <activity android:name=".Profiler" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Rules"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Settings"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Help"></activity>
```

And the functions called are these:

```
public void loadProfileLayout()        { startActivity(new Intent(this, Profiler.class)); }
public void loadRulesLayout(View v)    { startActivity(new Intent(this, Rules.class)); }
public void loadSettingsLayout(View v) { startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class)); }
public void loadHelpLayout(View v)   { startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class)); }
```

So initially this works. From the main "Profile" activity I am able to navigate to any of the other 3. And from the other 3 I can navigate anywhere but back to the main one. When I press the main activity button the application crashes. I try and debug, but it doesn't even appear to be executing loadProfileLayout(). Eclipse opens a "View.class" file with the contents of basically "Source not found". If I press F8 to continue debugging it loads "ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()"... again, "Source not found". Pressing F8 again will load the error message in the emulator "Sorry! The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Again, I am new to Android and all I know of activities is what I've been reading on the dev website. Am I making a fundamental mistake here I am not aware of?

Thanks,
Nate

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing you any grief but you'll also want to change the names in your <activity> tags to have . (period) before them. For example, <activity android:name="Rules"></activity> should be <activity android:name=".Rules"></activity>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was a typo in your question, but `loadProfileLayout()` also needs to take a `View` as its only parameter:

```
public void loadProfileLayout(View v)
```

**Edit**: The View parameter is the View that caused the `onClick` event (in your case, the `Button` instance).  I haven't looked at the code, but I assume that View is using reflection to find the method to call (specifically one that takes a View as an argument), and since it doesn't find a matching method, it decides to throw an exception.

Comment: That was the problem. Can you provide any insight on this argument? What exactly is passed that is used? I included View v in the others because that was how it was shown on the dev site. But I am not actually using the v object in my function. What is it's purpose and why does the application crash without it?

Comment: Added some additional text.  Hope that helps!

Comment: It does. Thanks for your help, Erich.